# Create a List of All Webmaps within a Portal

Tags: csv, arcgis-portal, list

I'm trying to do some spring cleaning and in the plans of organizing and archiving older webmaps.

We have several hundred maps, so I'm looking for a way to create a simple CSV that will list all webmaps. With a CSV I will be able to track my progress better.

Does Portal have any way to do this?

Admin Tools for ArcGIS Online does this for AGOL, but not for free in portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To try this, you will need to adjust the variables in all caps at the beginning. This will also return all web mapping applications. If you only want web maps, remove the asterisk (which acts as a wildcard) from *`item_type="Web Map*"`*. If you have trouble running this from your preferred IDE, just run it in the Python window within the ArcGIS Pro application.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import pandas as pd
import os


PORTAL_URL = "PORTAL URL"
USERNAME = "USERNAME"
PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
OUTPATH = "OUTPUT PATH"
OUTNAME = "OUTPUT NAME"
MAX_ITEMS_RETURNED = 1000

portal = GIS(PORTAL_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
search_result = portal.content.search(query='owner:*', item_type="Web Map*",max_items = MAX_ITEMS_RETURNED)
pd.DataFrame(search_result).to_csv(os.path.join(OUTPATH,OUTNAME) + ".csv")
```

For more info visit https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/accessing-and-creating-content/